# Using XSLT to find nodes given a set of parameters

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Sorry about the title — wasn’t sure how to word it.

Basically I have some XML like this:

```
<countries>
    <country handle="bangladesh"/>
    <country handle="india"/>
    <country handle="pakistan"/>
</countries>
```

And some XSLT like this (which doesn’t work):

```
<xsl:template match="/countries">
    <xsl:param name="popular"/>        
    <xsl:apply-templates select="country[count($popular/country[@handle = current()/@handle]) &gt; 0]" />
</xsl:template>    
<xsl:template match="/countries/country">
    …
</xsl:template>
```

I want to pass in a list of popular destinations like this:

```
<popular>
    <country handle="india"/>
    <country handle="pakistan"/>
</popular>
```

…to the /countries template and have it only operate on the ones in the $popular param. At the moment this simply does nothing. Changing the selector to country[true()] operates on them all, so at least I know the basic structure is right.

Any ideas? I think I may be getting confused by what is currently “current()”.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for the shortest, simplest and most in the spirit of XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than you think:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <popular>
    <xsl:copy-of select="/countries/country[@handle=$popular/country/@handle]"/>
  </popular>
</xsl:template>
```

**Edit**

The above was simply showing what was wrong with the OP's original XPath query.  Here's a full working example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="popular"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/countries">
        <xsl:with-param name="popular" select="$popular"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/countries">
    <xsl:param name="popular"/>
    <countries>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="country[@handle=$popular/country/@handle]"/>
    </countries>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and a program to call it:

```
static void Main(string[] arguments)
{
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load("xsltfile1.xslt");

    XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
    d.LoadXml(@"
<popular>
  <country handle='india'/>
  <country handle='xxx'/>
</popular>");

    XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
    args.AddParam("popular", "", d.DocumentElement);
    xslt.Transform("xmlfile1.xml", args, Console.Out);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Did the OP ever mention he needed a C#-bound solution?

Comment: The XSLT isn't C#-bound.  You can pass parameters into XSLT transforms from any language that has an XSLT processor.

Comment: Excellent, thank you—I new it would be something simple like this. I’ve been working with XSLT for a while now but for some reason had a complete mental block on this one.

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer! Matching root and matching root element next? Also, shadowing parameter in template rule?

Answer (score 2):

**The solution to this problem is simple and straightforward** (no need for string encoding or recursion).

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pPopular">
    <country handle="india"/>
    <country handle="pakistan"/>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vPopular" 
  select="document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pPopular']"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="country">
  <xsl:if test="@handle = $vPopular/*/@handle">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<countries>
    <country handle="bangladesh"/>
    <country handle="india"/>
    <country handle="pakistan"/>
</countries>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<countries>
    <country handle="india"/>
    <country handle="pakistan"/>
</countries>
```

Comment: What's the point of creating $vPopular?  Why can't you just use $pPopular?  In fact, won't doing it this way make the stylesheet produce the same results irrespective of what value the calling program passes in via the pPopular parameter?

Comment: @Robert-Rossney: On the contrary. Have you heard of RTF? If you want the parameter's default values to be accessible and useful, you have to take care of converting the RTF to a "normal" tree. Also, this is a good coding practice to be able to test the stylesheet independently of the external caller.

Comment: When I test this transform in .NET, it ignores whatever value of $pPopular my program passes in and always uses the value present in the XSLT file.  The XSLT recommendation does not define the mechanism whereby parameters get passed into XSLT transforms; it looks like the technique you're using assumes that the mechanism is actual modification of the XSLT document tree.

Comment: @Robert-Rossney: I think this was a bug in .NET 1.1. It must have been fixed in .NET 2.

Comment: I tested this with .NET 3.5.  Also, I don't think .NET's behavior is incorrect.  I can find nothing in the XSLT recommendation that specifies that stylesheet parameters should be accessible via the `document` function, or that it's desirable (or even acceptable) for external programs to set parameters by changing the contents of an `xsl:param` element.

Comment: @Robert-Rossney: Any node of an XSLT stylesheet is accessible using the document() function -- as the stylesheet is an XML file.

Comment: @Dimitre: I think your answer is best, but you need to invert **xsl:param** and **xsl:variable** elements in order to work with provide parameter as well as with "inline" parameter.

Comment: @Alejandro You are absolutely right. I am using this as a convenience -- just to simulate passing the parameters from outside.

Nothing prohibits setting and using the parameters within the stylesheet without any external caller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do with a recursive template. You must pass the popular destinations as a comma separated list (like this: `"'india,pakistan,'"`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/countries">
    <xsl:param name="popular" select="'india,pakistan,'" />
    <xsl:for-each select="country">
        <xsl:call-template name="print-country-from-list">
      <xsl:with-param name="pc" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="listc" select="$popular"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/countries/country">
   ... <xsl:value-of select="@handle"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="print-country-from-list">
  <xsl:param name="pc"/>
  <xsl:param name="listc" select="''"/>
  <xsl:variable name="h" select="substring-before($listc, ',')"/>
  <xsl:if test="$h">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pc/@handle=$h">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$pc" />
      </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="print-country-from-list">
        <xsl:with-param name="pc" select="$pc"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="listc" select="substring-after($listc, ',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is the 2 countries.